# Testcontainers with Dynalite in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins-pipeline, testcontainers, dynalite

Recently I expirienced problem with testcontainers.
I am using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynalite</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Part from test class:

```
    @Rule
    public DynaliteContainer dynamoDB2 =
            new DynaliteContainer(DockerImageName.parse("harbor-main.test.com/teamb/dynalite").withTag("v1.2.1-1")
                    .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("quay.io/testcontainers/dynalite"));
```

I can successfully run tests in IDE, but in Jenkins I get following:

```
 23/02/13 00:26:29 WARN TestcontainersConfiguration: 
Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/root/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. 
Exception message: FileNotFoundException: /root/.testcontainers.properties 
(No such file or directory)
```

I have properties file in classpath as well:
[image]

Is there any way to override config file path?

Comment: That is not a fatal error, just TC tries to find `.testcontainers.properties`  file in user's home directory and fails.

Comment: The files in picture are inside your project right? Try to add `.testcontainers.properties` inside /root folder, the warning should disappear

Comment: While I agree that it's not fatal error, maven is unable to execute tests in Jenkins. I believed there might be a simple solution where I can specify the correct path to my config file, which are located in target/test-classes/testcontainers.properties.